# Node net.createServer(), sending data back to the client oustside of on( 'data' ) callback

Tags: javascript, server

So I have a little server going in Electron, using net and with this class:

```
var net = require('net')

class Server {

    constructor(port) {

        this.Port = port

        var HOST = '127.0.0.1'  // todo: get ip from host name

        this.Server = net.createServer();
        this.Server.listen(port, HOST);

        this.Server.on('connection',  (sock) => {

            console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);

            sock.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log( `client sent data ${data}`)
                sock.write( `Server sends back ${data} to client`)
            });

            sock.on('close', function (data) {
                let index = sockets.findIndex(function (o) {
                    return o.remoteAddress === sock.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === sock.remotePort;
                })
                console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
            });
        });

    } // constructor

}
```

and I call it thus:

```
var server = new Server( 3000 )
```

testing it with `telnet localhost 3000`. And it all works dandy but it's kind of tied into a question and answer thing, only sending a response to the client when it's received data from the client in io('data'). Is there any way to send data from, say, outside the class, in a more arbitrary way. As in, for example:

```
var server = new Server( 3000 )
this.Server.write( data )
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

in the this.Server.on('connection') in the constructor:

```
this.Socket = sock
```

add the method:

```
Send( msg ) {
    if ( !this.Socket ) {
        console.log( "Server.Send(): no client connected" )
    }
    this.Socket.write( msg )
}
```

and in sock.on( 'close' ) set the socket method back to null:

```
this.Socket = null
```

then:

```
var server = new Server( 3000 )
server.Send( data )
```

(needs a check for a connection)